# Why do I have so many flags waiting for review?

Tags: support, flags

Currently I have 56 flags waiting for review and the oldest I could find dates back to Oct 30 '13.
Most seem to be for Off-topic, Unclear or Too Broad

After the purge of the close votes queue, where it actually hit 0, I still had pending flags open.

Are these old flags currently in some kind of limbo due to changes to the system?

Comment: The queue didn't really hit 0. It just showed a subset. If several of them are of the "other" type, I think that mod-queue is currently also fairly significant.

Comment: [Our resident reptile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) has recently mentioned that moderators were a little overwhelmed. That may explain the delay.

Answer (score 8):

They are waiting for review because there are over 1,100 moderator flags - mainly 800 "other" flags - for the moderators to work through and over 10,000 questions in the close review queue.

Moderators are volunteers who have given up some of their spare time to helping the sites so they can't be expected to be on the site all the time processing flags (though a number of them to appear to do just that).

Handling flags takes time. Some - like flags on comments - are easy to process. Others, like the custom "Other" flags take longer as the situation is more complex and requires that we do some investigation.

You might say that we need to add more moderators - but that's been demonstrated not to help that much. What we need is for the community - those with access to the review queues (and to a lesser extent the 10k moderation tools) to do more.

Comment: Actually, most (if not all) of the pending flags I see are close flags.

Comment: @BoltClock - ah. I'll add a note about the length of the close queue.

Comment: People with access to 10k moderation tools can't do that much actually. I haven't seen any flag in the 10k tools the last days...

Comment: @WouterJ - It's mainly the close review queue then.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about them not being dealt with immediately I understand there is a hefty workload for moderators.

Comment: Do the off-topic, unclear and too broad flag reason fall under this "other" category? Or is that simply for ones with custom text? I ask because what mainly confused me was how the close votes queue was cleared to 0 but I still had a bunch pending. (Which is why I asked if a subset of existing flags were put into a limbo state)

Comment: @Amicable - The off topic flags feed the close review queue. Moderators don't see those. The close votes queue isn't cleared.

Comment: It's way more than 10,000 in the close view.  Probably closer to 100K if you count all the hidden items (which includes questions that only have one close flag).