# Add rep on successful audits to motivate reviewers a bit more

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, gamification

So I was looking at e.g. [ChrisF's answer on why flags take so long to clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252923/4099598) when I had a thought: if more motivation is desired, and if audits are classically one of the main annoyances in reviewing, perhaps tagging +1 rep to all successful audits would make high-rep users somewhat more eager to keep plugging along.

Of course, this still has the problem that audits are arguably not high enough quality yet to have rep stacked on top, but for that and the existing reasons, it might be possible to have a manual audit selection process, where highly-trusted reviewers (those that get audits at the minimum/zero rate?) can select whether a post should be used as an audit or not. This could be added to the current algorithm and audit posts limited to a given pool, with the result that bad audits would be filtered out fairly rapidly and good audits would remain, at least until they'd served their purpose. (Reusing an audit indefinitely is probably not desirable, so after a few dozen or no more than a hundred, an audit is likely played out.)

This is fairly similar to [better review audits, better review ban tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272472/4099598), but manages the audit rejection case a bit better, I think. Still, there's probably a lot of subtleties I'm not fully aware of.

Comment: It's more complicated than you imagine it to be. As one of the frequent reviewers of the 10,000 post close votes queue which ChrisF mentioned, I can tell you it takes a lot of careful decision making and thinking to cast each vote, and moreover, seeing so many low quality posts is depressing. Also, gaming it would be dangerous. Posts should be moderated by users who really care about the quality of the site, even if it is a slow process. You wouldn't want your posts closed by folks who didn't take time to read and understand the post, and did it just for getting 1-rep, would you?

Comment: Why would high rep users care about +1 rep in the first place? And like @InfiniteRecursion pointed out I would much rather see an overflowing queue than seeing people doing reviews just for rep.

Comment: I don't review because of audit-annoyance. Adding rep would do absolutely nothing to get me back to reviewing - I already have far more reputation than I need for anything I want to do on SO. I don't review because I find it extremely frustrating when I spend the time and thought to review an item, only to be told I'm not paying attention because I saw something the audit system missed. Even when I agree with the audit system, it still wasted my time on a dummy question.

Comment: Rep for reviews wouldn't motivate the reviewers, just the opposite. It would demotivate them to do a lot of poor reviews only for rep.

Comment: So, what I'm getting is that it won't motivate reviewers because they already have enough rep, but also that it will motivate reviewers to abuse the system for the trivial rep gains. Which is it?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, that annoyance of having wasted time on a dummy audit is what I was hoping to address with a little consolation prize: pass audit, get rep which is normally not available for reviews at all. Whether or not that would actually work is, of course, another question, but I think the feeling of a bit of achievement at having proved reliable might be more effective than you'd think. Or, at least, that it's worth investigating rather than going off pure intuition.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I can only say it would definitely not motivate me - that is just one data point.  As far as "which is it" is concerned, I think the argument is that being motivated by +1 rep is likely to be positively correlated with gaming the system, and negatively correlated with being likely to do a good job of reviewing.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: OK, that's a bit clearer. That does make me wonder to what extent the exact amount correlates, though; i.e. whether +10 or +100 has a different characteristic.

Comment: @NathanTuggy At this point, no amount of reputation would make any difference to me. I already have all the privileges I need. There is nothing SO can give me that is of any value to me other than the opportunity to help new programmers.

Answer (score 4):

No, all this would do is encourage audit gaming. We already have had to deal with a number of people who try to cheat the audit system using various techniques (search Meta for a list of them, because I won't link to them here).

Badges were enough to trigger terrible review abuse. Adding reputation into any moderation-related action will lead to much worse problems.

As I [expand upon here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275272/19679), manual review for selection of audits is not scalable. Instead, we need [a system for identification and removal of bad audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790). That would go a long way toward fixing the problems good reviewers have had with audits.

Also, ChrisF's answer largely has to do with moderator flags. There are no audits involved in moderator flag handling. The way to attack that problem is to have better filtering and direction of flags.

For example, see the recent movement of "low quality" and "not an answer" flags into community review, combined with the new question triage system. That took a large burden off of the few moderators and distributed it among active members in the community. No incentives were needed or that to work well. I hold out hope that the triage system will improve upon this.

Comment: You really don't expand much on the reason for non-scalability of manual audit selection, though, which I'd appreciate.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - If moderators had to hand-pick audits, that would take a tremendous amount of our already limited time and there's no way we could find and identify enough ongoing audit cases to populate review. If the community had to pick these, that would be ripe for abuse and would end up effectively being what we have today (the community currently "picks" these with their votes and flags). If humans pick each audit case, the complaints would shift from the system to arguments over what should and should not have been picked as an audit, and we'd be wasting our time with that instead.

Comment: Assuming I got http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/256690/review-task-counts-on-a-typical-day right, there's about 6600 reviews/day. So scaling a given audit to be used to check 100+ reviewers would leave maybe 65-75 audits to pick per day. If we limit audit picking to approving or disapproving of current-algorithm-generated selections, wouldn't that scale fairly well?

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Again, who is going to be judging these? If moderators, no we're not going to have the time to review 60+ posts a day just to judge audit cases, and your guess is a very low number for what we'd actually need. If the community, we'll have people abusing that review queue just like all the others (why we need audits in the first place), and we'll be back to complaining about bad audit cases. I really do feel that the best solution is to deal with the relatively rare bad system-picked audit cases as they happen and to be able to remove those from circulation.

Comment: Well, as long as you've understood what I'm getting at, I can't really argue with the mod perspective on things, given my lack of experience there.