# Why bother flagging posts / comments?

Tags: discussion

OK, so I understand people moderate for free, I understand that flagging helps deal with the crud. I understand there are badges for flagging to encourage users to do so. But, as I look down my list of flags, I see 30+ pending, representing maybe 1/6th of all my flags since Stackoverflow reset the counter. Some of these are days old, some weeks, some many weeks. I doubt these will be seen to, and will lie unverified.

So if only a portion of their flags will be credited to the user (leaving aside those that are declined/disputed), then why bother flagging posts for badges when their time could be better spent?

Yes, before you answer about how it improves the community, makes you feel good etc etc, please see this from the point of view of users who only do things for the badges and not necessarily for the community. Gamification exists because it tries to answer the "what's in it for me" question to users.

#### Rephrasing

Ok, so the crux of my question is as to why is there a pretty bad flags pending level when Stack Overflow actually needs to encourage flagging posts in the first place for the good of the community and should be rewarding flaggers by reviewing them?

Comment: I don't share your experience of so many waiting for review. Could you specify what types of flags you've raised and in what tags?

Comment: Pretty much across the board, I haven't found a certain tag to be 'pending' heavy. The flags are mostly off-topic to opinion-based. I find low-quality to just almost flat out be declined most times.

Comment: Well, you're speaking for your own case, you're generalizing something you don't know for sure that's happening across SO, in my case, I don't have a lot of flags waiting for review.

Comment: Well, it's happening for me, therefore it's happening for at least a good proportion of users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have so many flags waiting for review?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252898/why-do-i-have-so-many-flags-waiting-for-review)

Comment: I used to check my flags to see if I was doing it correctly, once I knew it was ok I never looked back.

Answer (score 17):

Gamification only goes so far. If you don't have any intrinsic motivation, any desire to perform the activity for its own sake, then making it into a game will eventually fail to satisfy - or worse, will develop practices and motivations that are contrary to the intended purpose of the activity!

Badges and so on are useful as a form of encouragement, to show folks what is considered useful behavior and provide a token reward for trying it out. But at some point it *needs* to become unsatisfying, so that folks either find more meaningful reasons to continue participating or... stop before their participation becomes harmful.

Comment: So...Why bother flagging posts/comments as per the question?

Comment: You implied that you didn't want an answer about helping the community, so...

Comment: Is this question not a complaint over unattended flags rather than a philosophical discussion?

Comment: No I never. I rephrased my question in hopefully an easier to understand, and more direct manner

Comment: Beats me. I've been handling flags for the past couple of hours; I'm gonna drop that & eat some bratwurst.

Comment: @Shog9 bon appetit!

Answer (score 9):

> The flags are mostly off-topic to opinion-based.

These flags end up in the close vote review queue which is always pretty full, currently there are 10.5k questions with outstanding close votes awaiting review.

> I find low-quality to just almost flat out be declined most times.

If you're finding that a majority of your flags are being declined, you're doing it wrong. Sorry there isn't really a better way to put that. Re-evaluate your flagging practices or stop flagging altogether.

If your **only** motive for flagging is to gain badges, again, re-evaluate your flagging practices or stop flagging altogether.

Some guidance:

[When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)
[What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

Comment: "If your only motive for flagging is to gain badges, again, re-evaluate your flagging practices or stop flagging altogether", so you're saying all those users who are helping the community by flagging (albeit for a "badge") should stop doing so? Also, if the queues are so full, then why can't SO employ moderators like I suspect a company that owned a forum this size most likely would as flags that are perhaps pointing out a poor question/answer are going amiss inturn harming the community.

Comment: @user3791372 The review queues are mostly handled by common users with more than 3k rep. It used to be more like 100k, so things have improved a lot.

Comment: @user3791372 If your **only** motive is the badge, then yes please stop.

Comment: Reducing the rep barrier seems to be more out of necessity / desperation rather than "improving"!

Comment: @user3791372 Umm, what? Did you mean to post that on another answer?

Comment: So again, all those flaggers who are doing it for the badge should stop? Why? Who's going to replace them? I think Stack Overflow the company would disagree with you as it's the reason why the badge is there in the first place.

Comment: @user3791372 so.... the problem is >3K don't necessarily burn ALL their close votes each day. I know I don't... Why? well... you know, I have a life, and not necessarily time to do it. When I was under 3K, I was flagging and asking the same question (never posted on meta, but I always found it weird).... not much to do. Stack will not employ moderators for stuff like that (and neither should they, really)

Comment: @Patrice Won't employ people to do stuff like what? Moderating poor questions so the site isn't filled with lots of rubbish making the site harder to use? Ain't nobody got time for that, or in SO's case, ain't nobody want to spend money on that?

Comment: @user3791372 I don't see why stack would have to pay for that... or how community can dictate how Stack will spend their money. I'm not saying I don't see the benefit to having this queue be empty. Just saying I don't foresee Stack spending money on that, or a reason for them to do this. They care about generating MONEY from the site, which is easy to do since most of the moderation is handled by users. If they start pouring money into moderation that kinda goes away

Comment: Until users go away because a new site (with moderators) comes along.

Comment: @Patrice, SO pours *lots* of money into moderation, but they try to make that money scale. If they hire one person to moderate, they can only get 8 man-hours of moderation per day per person. If they, instead, spend the money on developing better moderation tools, and better algorithms to automatically detect and clean up garbage, they can get *hundreds* to *thousands* of man-hours worth of moderation from the community. The main problem is that the better it gets, the more popular it is meaning the more garbage gets tracked in. It's like visiting any popular beach, more people, more trash.

Comment: @user3791372 It's interesting that you say that, seeing as Quora ended up [going for the same model as SO](https://blog.quora.com/Moderation-at-Scale-Distributing-Power-to-More-People), only difference being that they don't allow "normal" users to do the flagging. Apart from that their "reporting" is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

No one forces you to flag the posts/comments, simple as that. You **choose** to flag them, reasoning behind it its entirely up to you.

I personally could not care less for those who only do it for the badges.

Comment: So...Why should anyone flag questions/comments?

Comment: Because its for the good of the community, whether it gets approved/declined or ignored it's not longer your responsibility. You've done your part, and SO thanks you for that. You aren't held responsible for reviewers' actions or lack of them.

Comment: see the end of the question. I know it has a positive effect on the community etc.

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Comment: @user3791372 Because they want to help the community and don't have strictly egocentric reasons for doing so. If that does not apply to you then you don't need to bother with flagging.

Answer (score 4):

While some types of flags (e.g. spam/offensive, flags about user meltdowns, etc.) are processed much more quickly than others (e.g. flags about bad reviews, flags requesting custom migration), in my experience very nearly all flags are eventually processed. Therefore, in the long run the "pending flags level" is actually quite low. For instance right now I have 12 pending flags out of a total of 7,198 that I have ever raised, for a tiny pending flag rate of 0.2% (and I used all 100 of my flags today). Therefore from a gamification perspective, you may need to wait a bit for each flag to get processed, but it almost certainly will eventually count toward the deputy/marshal badges (or not, if it was a bad flag).

That being said, I hypothesize that most of the flagging that happens on Stack Overflow is motivated by the desire to keep the site clean, not due to gamification. One clear piece of evidence is that many users (myself included) have stayed active flagging low-quality content despite having received the Marshal badge. Personally I find helping the community to be a much better motivator than getting a badge.

Comment: Well, you could point out that *none* of your flags are requesting closure, as you can vote for that (excluding rare custom flags on bounties).